# Access a nested JSON object property via a single string

Tags: json, typescript

This line: `let X = this.appGlobal.GetNavigationLanguage().data;`
retuns JSON as you can see below.
[image]

> I want to take **NAV.REPORTS.BMAIL.TITLE**.

Translate code (*NAV.REPORTS.BMAIL.TITLE*) is dynamically created.

1. `X.NAV.REPORTS.BMAIL.TITLE` => works
2. `X['NAV']['REPORTS']['BMAIL']['TITLE']` => works

But keep in mind I have dynamically created translation code I need something like this:

```
let transCode = 'NAV.REPORTS.BMAIL.TITLE';
console.log(X[transCode]);
```

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you split the `transCode` by a `.` separator and then pick off the indeces as needed? If you're using other libraries, there are some good functions, like https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path.

Comment: I can but in that case, I must use double for iteration because every one item of navigation can have children. So I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
test_data = {
  NAV: {
    REPORTS: {
      BMAIL: {
        TITLE: "hello"
      }
    }
  }
}

let transCode = 'NAV.REPORTS.BMAIL.TITLE';
properties = transCode.split('.'); //--> ["NAV","REPORTS","BMAIL","TITLE"]

result = test_data
properties.forEach(function(property) {
  result = result[property]
})

console.log(result) // --> hello
```

Comment: This is a neat solution.

Answer (score 1):

The short and evil route would be the following:

```
console.log(eval(`X.${transCode}`));
```

The less evil way is to use a recursive function call, this means you only look into the number of items in your string-path (rather than looping the whole collection).

```
const X = {
    NAV: {
        REPORTS: {
            BMAIL: {
                TITLE: 'Test'
            }
        }
    }
}


const transCode = 'NAV.REPORTS.BMAIL.TITLE';

// Evil...
console.log(eval(`X.${transCode}`));  // Test

// Less Evil (but needs exception handling)...
function getData(input: any, splitPath: string[]) {
    const level = splitPath.pop();

    if (splitPath.length === 0) {
        return input[level];
    } else {
        return getData(input[level], splitPath);
    }
}

const result = getData(X, transCode.split('.').reverse());

console.log(result); // Test
```